# django creating a row in userprofile table when a user is created

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, user-profile

I am following this(https://www.django-tips.com/tutorial/django-tutorial-with-twitter-app/1/?page=3) tutorial to create a twitter clone app with django. But in the project, user will be created through the django default user creation system.

The problem is, I want to create a row in userprofile table when a user is created. Otherwise the user is creating and I have to insert it in the userprofile table bu accessing the admin section of the project. How can I do this?

the model looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
 relation = models.ManyToManyField(
     'self',
     through='Relation',
     symmetrical=False,
     related_name='related_to',
     default=None
 )
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.get_full_name()

 class Relation(models.Model):
  follower = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='follows')
  is_followed = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='followers')
  follow_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
     return '%s follows %s' % (self.follower.user.username, self.is_followed.user.username)

  class Meta:
     unique_together = ('follower', 'is_followed')
```

And the tutorial also mentioned to create a signal but they haven't cleared where this file will be created, so I have followed the official doc and created the signals.py file.

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

So, I am stuck at this stage and I can't move forward. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you don't have to create signals file... just after the UserProfile

```
from django.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ....

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: cheers. I am really a newbie but the help is much apprechiated.

Comment: Awesome. It reduces the signal deployment complexity very well.

Answer (score 0):

To create a row in userprofile table after user is created(by models.py), you can either do from admin interface or from shell or by creating a form in front-end and then POSTing and saving it. ( I'm giving you sample code - various attributes in it might not be of use to you right now. Just for your understanding).

The shell approach can be something like this:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth import User
>>> from <package_profile>.models import UserProfile
>>> new_user = UserProfile(user_auth = new_user, name = name,...) # other whatever fields you want
>>> new_user.save()
```

Form approach can be something like this:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from <package_profile>.models import USerProfile, Developer
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    @login_required
    def page(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = Form_inscription(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name     = form.cleaned_data['name']
            login    = form.cleaned_data['login']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        # User auth details:-   
            new_user            = User.objects.create_user(username = login, password = password)
            new_user.is_active  = True
            new_user.email      = email
            new_user.first_name = name
            new_user.save()
            new_developer       = Developer(user_auth = new_user, name = name, email = email)
            new_developer.save()
            return HttpResponse("Developer added")
        else:
            return render(request, create_developer.html', {'form' : form})
    else:
        form = Form_inscription()
        return render(request,create_developer.html', {'form' : form})

    class Form_inscription(forms.Form):
        name     = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=30)
        login    = forms.CharField(label = "Login")
        email    = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
        password = forms.CharField(label = "Password", widget = forms.PasswordInput)
        password_bis = forms.CharField(label = "Password Re-enter", widget = forms.PasswordInput)

        def clean(self): 
            cleaned_data = super(Form_inscription, self).clean()
            password = self.cleaned_data.get('password') 
            password_bis = self.cleaned_data.get('password_bis')
            if password and password_bis and password != password_bis:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords are not identical.") 
            return self.cleaned_data
```

Corresponding html of the form will be:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block title_html %}
  Create Developer/User
{% endblock %}

{% block h1 %}
  Create Developer
{% endblock %}

{% block article_content %}
  <form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
   </table>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me to understand :)